# Set default options for matplot/plot

Tags: r

I would like to set default styles for the plot/matplot functions. For instance, I almost always use

`matplot(x, y, type='l', lty='solid', col=rainbow(), lwd=2)`

so I would like to set default options of `type='l', lty='solid', col=rainbow(), lwd=2` in .Rprofile. Of course, I could just make a new function,

```
mplot <- function(x, y, type='l', lty='solid', lwd=2, col=rbow(), log='') {
        matplot(x, y, type=type, lty=lty, col=col, log=log, lwd=lwd)
}
```

but if I want to specify `xlim` and/or `ylim` or set `xaxt='n'` etc. it becomes a lot of work since there are more default options that I want than those I don't want. I also thought something like

```
plist <- list(type=type, lty=lty, col=col, log=log, lwd=lwd)
matplot(x, y, plist)
```

should work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```r
do.call(matplot, c(list(x, y), plist))
```

it should work.  The other option is to use `...`:

```r
mplot <- function(x, y, type='l', lty='solid', lwd=2, col=rbow(), log='', ...) {
        matplot(x, y, type=type, lty=lty, col=col, log=log, lwd=lwd,
           ...)
}
```

Comment: The good ole ...